# what is causing this white gap between header and start of main menu in ie8

Tags: html, css

Something happend when I replaced a footer for a sticky footer, I really dont have a idea where it happend because I usually test the website in Firefox and then ie 8 is allways as good as FF.

Something in my code has created a mayor gap between the upper top menu and my main menu.

[My website](http://www.friesecomputerservice.nl/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing F12 in IE8. That will bring up the IE Developer Tools which have "Browser Mode" selections in the menu bar. Check if the browser is set to IE7 mode rendering. Which if I change mine to that, it will drop the content below the "contact" button on the left. If you have compatibility mode on that will also cause this behavior.

If you would like to force the most recent (IE8) browser rendering engine in IE, you can use the following meta tag in the `<head>` of your site.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

That said, there is a more "progressive" setting which will use the very most recent version of the rendering engine, (eg: IE9 when it is available) however this can have unpredictable results when that browser does become officially available. (Unless you test it and fix any issues before that happens)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/beyonddoctype).

Comment: The browser was set to copatibility mode :s, the thing is, how can I change it so when people have their website (like I had) in compatibility mode will see a nice website :)

Answer (score 0):

Display inline on the wrapsite_content div instead of block
and remove the clear both on the div with the class cb

Works in IE have not checked it in firefox

Answer (score 0):

The class `"set_menu_bar"` has a inline style of `"padding-top: 35px;"` this might be causing your issue.